# nswag studio generate model classes into separate files

Tags: nswag

I've been using Autorest in the past and it automatically creates interfaces and separates the models into separate files, which appears to be cleaner.

I just switched over to Nswag Studio lately and couldn't find the option to separate files. Is there an option in the generation that I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using NSwag <= v13.18.2.0 (latest version at time of this answer). However, there is an easy way to split the generated file up into multiple files using an IDE like Visual Studio or JetBrains Rider.

In Rider, you can put your cursor on the name of the first type in the generated file, open the action list (`ALT`+`ENTER`) and select `Move types to matching files in file`.

[image]

This will generate a file for each type in the generated file.

I'm pretty sure Visual Studio should have a similar feature.